# Capture Java program name/package name from process command line using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract Java program name/package name from its process command line. An example of process command-line is

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8/bin/java -Dzookeeper.datadir.autocreate=false -Dzookeeper.log.dir=/var/log/zookeeper -Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,ROLLINGFILE -cp /usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-2.11.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.15.0.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/etc/zookeeper/conf::/etc/zookeeper/conf:/usr/lib/zookeeper/*:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/* -Dzookeeper.log.threshold=INFO -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/zookeeper/conf-d/zoo.cfg

I need to capture org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/zookeeper/conf-d/zoo.cfg

I am using a regex (?:(?:.*bin/|^)java\s.*?-cp)(?:\s.*jar.*?)+(\s(?:(?!-).)+) which captures org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain /etc/zookeeper/conf.

Need help in fixing the regex or a better way of capturing the program name.

Comment: No need for regex. Just split into whitespace-separated strings, then drop the first string (path to `java` executable) and all strings that start with `-` (flags) until you encounter the first one that doesn't start with `-` (the class in dotted notation).

Comment: @DanielPryden I could do that. However, there are some more use cases associated with this regex. So I would prefer regex based solution.